# SSMS Configuration - removing []

Tags: ssms

I've been using SSMS for some time and never had to use brackets [] around table names. Yesterday I obtained my new laptop asset and on the new install/version (18.12.1) I now need to add the brackets for it to recognize the objects. What setting is there that eliminates this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the code in which the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the setting is but I copied the

NewSettings.vssettings

file from the old laptops sql server management studio folder.